# How to cascade delete from same MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, cascading-deletes

Is it possible to cascade delete from same MySQL table? I want to cascade delete in a table that references itself in relations.

Example:

I have a `comments` table that has `comment_id` and `parent_id`, where `parent_id` is the same id in `comment_id`.

`Parent_id` could be either another `comment_id` or `null` if it's a root
comment.

I want to be able to select any node in this tree and delete it. In the process, all child nodes and sub-child nodes should be deleted.

I have tried to alter my table using this query

```
ALTER TABLE `comment` 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`) 
    REFERENCES `comment`(`parent_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

but I end up with an error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`zendaya001`.`#sql-6c1_1044ab`, CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_3` FOREIGN
> KEY (`comment_id`) REFERENCES `comment` (`parent_id`) ON DELETE
> CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT)

**For reproduction, this is my comment table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `comment_id` int NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count_replies` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count_likes` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for table `comment`
--
ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  ADD KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`);
```

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data.

Comment: “I want to be able to select any node in this tree and delete it” - so not only delete child nodes, but parent nodes, too? So if you have `A` with a child of `B` which further has a child of `C`, when deleting `B` both `A` and `C` would get deleted?

Comment: @ChrisHaas no, when deleting B, C would get deleted. but when deleting A, B and C should get deleted as well.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for `comments`.

Comment: See the [help] for more on [how to ask good questions](/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics. See also the [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: *this is my comment table* It does not contain any UNIQUE index - so you cannot refer to it.

Comment: @Akina sorry I just had to get this out quickly, comment_id is defined as the **PRIMARY KEY** while parent_id defined as **INDEX**

Comment: Edit the script - it must be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create the foreign key with incorrect direction.

Must be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `comment` 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) 
    REFERENCES `comment`(`comment_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/iJRlziwL

`comment_id` must be defined at least UNIQUE (maybe PRIMARY KEY).

---

> I cannot insert a new record into the table even if ON UPDATE RESTRICT is also set to CASCADE – Freesoul

You do something wrongly.

https://dbfiddle.uk/rcUupB2b

Comment: comment_id is defined as the PRIMARY KEY. Apparently, this works but then I cannot insert a new record into the table even if ON UPDATE RESTRICT is also set to CASCADE

Comment: @Freesoul There is no problems with INSERT, answer updated.

Comment: Oh, yeah it was my fault. From my code, I was filling the parent_id with a value that doesn't exist on comment_id. Thanks @Akina